# Symfony 6 AWS Beanstalk run npm run build

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and I've gotten as far as getting the following error in Symfony:

*Asset manifest file "/var/app/current/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.*

In local, this would be fixed by running `npm run build`.  I've tried adding `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` in the environment variables, but I think that might just be for node.js apps?

I've also tried SSHing onto the EC2 instance and installing node on there, but I ran into errors trying to install either npm or nvm.  I feel like this is the wrong approach anyway, since it seems like the idea of beanstalk is that you shouldn't need to ssh onto the instance.

Perhaps I should just include the node_modules folder in the zip uploaded, but since one of the recommended ways to produce the zip is to use git, this doesn't seem correct either.

Comment: Try `sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel` or follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Comment: It looks like you need to run a Webpack build. I would usually do that before I deploy it onto Beanstalk. Meaning that your zip file should already contain the build assets. However, you can automatize the process you are currently doing with hooks. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, it seems like there's 3 options here:

1. SSH onto the instance(s) and the following worked for me (Amazon Linux 2 - ARM chip)

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore)
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm install)
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm run build)
```

The problem with this, is if you have multiple instances that scale up and down with a load balancer, it isn't really practical to do this.

2. Add the above as a hook:

The following sh file could be put in the following directory: `.platform/hooks/predeploy`

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore)
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm install)
(cd /var/app/current/;sudo npm run build)
```

However, I've since learnt that it's best advised to just include the `node_modules` in the zip that gets uploaded.  I guess this way the time to get the server up is reduced.

3. Include the `node_modules` folder in the zip that gets uploaded.
   To include the `node_modules` folder, since this is naturally ignored by GIT, I used the EB CLI and added a `.ebignore` file, which is a clone of the `.gitignore` file, but includes the `node_modules` and `public` folders.  Also be cautious in your build process that you're not including the node dev dependencies.